# Can't boot Lubuntu iso from XBoot USB on my HP Laptop with i3-5005u & Full HD

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, laptop, 16.10

Can't boot Lubuntu iso from USB key (XBoot multiboot) on my HP Laptop with i3-5005u & Full HD.
Other ISOs like Kaspersky rescue disk are booting and working. When I select ubuntu the screen gets black. 
I Have selected Legacy mode in BIOS as I have already installed Win 7 and I have left partitions with grub & space to install Lubuntu.

Comment: is your windows in legacy mode as well?

Comment: My windows is in  legacy mode. I burned an iso in a DVD and it boots.